# LeetCode: TwoSum Solution

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a map in order to make the algorithm for this answer https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/#/description O(n), but for some reason i'm getting the improper indices for a lot of test cases i'm trying

From what I can tell, I'm doing the checks properly for the iterators, however these are kind of new to me, and i'm not entirely sure if i'm returning the correct indices that I want.

```
//My Code:



#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

std::vector<int> twoSum(int nums[], int size, int target)
{
    std::vector<int> answer;
    std::map<int, int> myMap;
    std::map<int, int>::iterator it;
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        myMap.insert(std::pair<int, int>(nums[i], i));
        int indexItOne = distance(myMap.begin(), myMap.find(nums[i]));
        int indexItTwo = distance(myMap.begin(), myMap.find(target-nums[i]));
        it = myMap.find(target - nums[i]);

        if (it != myMap.begin() || indexItOne != indexItTwo)
        {
            answer.push_back(i);
            answer.push_back(distance(myMap.begin(), myMap.find(target - nums[i])));
            return answer;
        }

    }//for

}//twoSum
```

Comment: Change this `it != myMap.begin()` to this `it != myMap.end()`... Actually scratch that. You have a bunch of finds that I got lost and cannot follow your logic.

Comment: What happens if the loop ends? What do you return then?

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know how myMap.begin() got in there but yes it most definitely should be myMap.end()

Comment: If the loop ends, i'm just simply returning nothing

Comment: In a function declared to return a value? That will lead to *undefined behavior!* The compiler should have warned about it.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I don't believe this is the root cause of the problem however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that the map should be a mapping from `num` to the index of that `num`, but it should not be inserted into the map right away. This is due to the constraint of the problem that

> you may not use the same element twice.

Therefore, the algorithm would go something more like this:

```
class Solution {
  public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
      // Create a mapping from num -> index of num
      unordered_map<int, int> m;

      for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        // Check if we have seen our buddy
        int buddy = target - nums[i];
        auto buddyIt = m.find(buddy);

        if(buddyIt != m.end()) {
          // Buddy found, return answer
          return vector<int>{ buddyIt->second, i };
        }

        // Buddy not found, insert current num into buddy map
        m[nums[i]] = i;
      }
    }
};
```